# How can I track incoming traffic on a specific port?

Tags: logging, port

I have a camera system on the network with remote users but the camera software does not log user signons, it just validates.
All the camera requests come in on a specific port.
Is there a way to monitor traffic on a specific port(incoming only)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's lots of ways, depending on what exactly you mean by "track" or "monitor".

- `iptables` rules keep a record of how many times a specific rule is hit; if you just want to know how many connections have been made to the camera, a rule that tracks SYN packets to the camera can be inserted into the firewall of any Linux box between the outside world and the camera.
- Netflow data can be exported from many different sorts of routers, which you can use to track connections in a variety of ways.
- `tcpdump` can be used to collect some or all of the data flowing to and from the camera; depending on what you want to know, a variety of information can be obtained by analysing the data in the TCP streams (including exactly what images were viewed, if you want) using custom-written analysis scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If linux based system, go with womble's answer, Howerver for windows based you can use wireshark.

Other very basic way of monitoring connections is "netstat -an" on both windows and linux and you can write a script to capture output of "netstat -an" every so often and do fancy stuff.